# Canvas(PHP) размер данных

Tags: php

Есть идеи как отправить на сервер изображение закодированное в base64.

Дело в том что лимит отправляемых данных составляет 65000 байт, закодированное изображение весом к примеру 1MB уже невозможно отправить так как размер данных превышает этот порог в разы.

Вот собственно ситуация, сталкивался ли кто, как лечились?

Comment: А если кусками?

Comment: Думал уже над этим, но гвоздь в том что мне нужно собрать изображение на сервере после отправки и сохранить.